# retrieve data by inner join with defined variable in Codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, inner-join

I want to get the following result of the mysql code by codeignitor.
It gives non equals id's(tbl_user) for the provided time frame in tbl_user_unavailability table

**MySql code**

```
SELECT tbl_user.id

FROM  tbl_user

INNER JOIN tbl_user_unavailability

on tbl_user_unavailability.user_id <> tbl_user.id

WHERE '2018-02-02' BETWEEN begin_date AND end_date;
```

**Result**

```
22

25
```

[find the mysql code result screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bZVDb.png)

to get this result by codeignitor ,I have used following codes

**Controller code**

public function test(){

```
     $current_date = '2018-02-02';

     $available_users = $this->mod_users->test_test($current_date);
     $data['available_users'] = $available_users;

     //to test the result array
     //var_dump($available_users);die();

     $data['related_view']='user_unavailable_new';
     $this->load->view('template', $data); 
}
```

**Model code**

public function test_test($current_date){

```
$this->load->database();
$this->db->select('*');    
$this->db->join('tbl_user_unavailability',  'tbl_user_unavailability.user_id <> tbl_user.id','inner');    
$this->db->where("'$current_date' BETWEEN  'tbl_user_unavailability.begin_date' AND 'tbl_user_unavailability.end_date'");
$query =  $this->db->get($this->table);
return $query->result_array();
```

}

**Result**

```
not showing anything

I have tested it with var_dump($available_users);die();

It shows empty array
```

Comment: I know is a little bit late but maybe it helps somebody else, with the command [$this->db->last_query()](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/helpers.html) you can print put your last query. I think you have an error in your WHERE part you should write tbl_user_unavailability.begin_date and tbl_user_unavailability.end_date without inverted commas.

Comment: @user141080 Thanku